# How can i check google play in-app purchase (in php)?

Tags: google-play, google-oauth, google-play-developer-api

I need some help to find a way to check a purchase in php.

To explain :
With my android app I can buy some in app product.
After the purchase , I call a webservice .
This WS have to check that the purchase was made. However this must be done automatically (script) so I must find a way to check the purchase without login.

I find this function "https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/purchases/products/get", however the problem is still the authentification...

Do you have a solution for me?

Thanks a lot !

J.